# Paginação simples em jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, paginação

Estou à procura de uma paginação simples, sem estilos CSS, nem nada do género. Apenas com os botões em baixo para mudar de página e com os elementos em cima. Estou a perguntar, porque os exemplos que encontro são um pouco complexos para mim.

Estou a carregar os dados usando php, ou seja, nunca tenho um número exacto de linhas. O que quero é que a paginação seja criada, de 10 em 10 elementos, imaginando que tenho 30 elementos.

Comment: Não creio que seja possível usando apenas javascript. A informação de quantas páginas tem precisa ser gerada de alguma forma, logo ou HTML tem que saber, ou PHP com Ajax para carregar as demais páginas

Comment: Com `XmlHttpRequest`? E porque motivo não seria possível ter o números de linhas só por causa do PHP?

Comment: sim, é possível saber o número de linhas por php. agora o resto é que é complicado..

Comment: Poderia especificar o que você quer? existem inúmeros meios de fazer uma paginação, depende muito do que você quer, por favor, especifique.

Comment: uma simples paginação, em que recebo n entradas, e quero fazer a paginação deles, por exemplo de 10 em 10 entradas

Comment: o básico para paginações é efetuar uma consulta COUNT aos dados sem filtros da paginação, para saber o número de registros totais (assim o número de páginas), e outra consulta com os filtros da paginação (qtd de itens por página, "offset": a partir de que índice) para retornar somente os dados da página atual

Comment: Já experimentou datatables.net ?

Comment: @groo nunca experimentei, aconselha a usar?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer paginação exclusivamente com jQuery/Javascript é ter os dados num vetor Javascript e então aplicá-los numa tabela com uma função específica.

Por exemplo, você pode usar o PHP para gerar o seguinte vetor (ou retorná-lo em formato JSON numa chamada Ajax):

```js
var dados = [
    ['Banana', '10,00'],
    ['Maça', '2,00'],
    ['Pera', '6,00'],
    ['Goiaba', '3,25'],
    ['Tamarindo', '1,50'],
    ['Cenoura', '0,75'],
    ['Alface', '0,99'],
    ['Tomate', '3,21'],
    ['Abacaxi', 'N/D'],
    ['Kiwi', '99,50'],
    ['Cebola', '1,15'],
    ['Alho', '1,02'],
    ['Abóbora', '4,75'],
    ['Pêssego', '2,33'],
    ['laranja', '2,99']
];
```

Imagine então um HTML básico contendo uma tabela vazia e os botões para avançar e retroceder, como segue:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Descrição</th>
            <th>Valor</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">Nenhum dado ainda...</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div>
    <button id="anterior" disabled>&lsaquo; Anterior</button>
    <span id="numeracao"></span>
    <button id="proximo" disabled>Próximo &rsaquo;</button>
</div>
```

Aí você vai precisar de alguns elementos fixos no código Javascript para determinar o tamanho da página de dados e qual é a página atual:

```js
var tamanhoPagina = 6;
var pagina = 0;
```

Também é necessário ter uma função para preencher os dados da página atual na tabela e, como bônus, mostrar o número da página:

```js
function paginar() {
    $('table > tbody > tr').remove();
    var tbody = $('table > tbody');
    for (var i = pagina * tamanhoPagina; i < dados.length && i < (pagina + 1) *  tamanhoPagina; i++) {
        tbody.append(
            $('<tr>')
                .append($('<td>').append(dados[i][0]))
                .append($('<td>').append(dados[i][1]))
        )
    }
    $('#numeracao').text('Página ' + (pagina + 1) + ' de ' + Math.ceil(dados.length / tamanhoPagina));
}
```

Seria interessante uma função para ativar ou desativar os botões `Próximo` e `Anterior` quando estivesse na último ou na primeira página, respectivamente. Também poderia desativar caso tivesse apenas uma página:

```js
function ajustarBotoes() {
    $('#proximo').prop('disabled', dados.length <= tamanhoPagina || pagina > dados.length / tamanhoPagina - 1);
    $('#anterior').prop('disabled', dados.length <= tamanhoPagina || pagina == 0);
}
```

Por fim, precisamos colocar o evento para avançar e retroceder nas páginas, além de inicializar tudo isso no carregamento da página HTML:

```js
$(function() {
    $('#proximo').click(function() {
        if (pagina < dados.length / tamanhoPagina - 1) {
            pagina++;
            paginar();
            ajustarBotoes();
        }
    });
    $('#anterior').click(function() {
        if (pagina > 0) {
            pagina--;
            paginar();
            ajustarBotoes();
        }
    });
    paginar();
    ajustarBotoes();
});
```

#### [Exemplo funcional no jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p57w5/)

Comment: e é possível com numeração em baixo?

Comment: @pc_oc Feito! É isso que você queria?

Comment: sim sim, muito obrigado! agora só espero conseguir meter os valores recebidos da base de dados para dentro do array dados!

Comment: Que resposta top. Muito Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a [Slickgrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki) para fazer isso.
É bem simples.
Neste [exemplo](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html) tem visualmente a paginação, mas não está implementada. Mas como disse, é simples de fazer.

Comment: é possível estilizar a exibição com Bootstrap?