# Atualizar uma tabela usando javascript e arrays

Tags: javascript, php, tabela-html

O que preciso fazer é simples, mas como sou iniciante na arte do PHP e Javascript, estou me batendo um pouco.

O que preciso fazer é o seguinte. Tenho uma tela de pedidos, onde vou cadastrar os dados do pedido, até aí, tudo bem. Logo mais abaixo, vou inserir os produtos no pedido, e eles serão mostrados logo abaixo para serem salvos assim que o pedido for salvo.

O que desejo fazer, é selecionar um produto num `combobox`, clicar no botão de adicionar produto, adicionar este produto num array ou algo que valha e exibir este array em uma tabela logo abaixo. Mas gostaria de fazer isto, sem atualizar a página.

Alguém tem alguma idéia ou exemplo de como fazer isto?

Comment: Ariel, só para esclarecer: quando você fala em tabela quer dizer tabela em base de dados certo? sabe o que é AJAX? Tem alguma framework de javascript (jQuery, Mootools, etc) ou quer fazer com JS puro? Responda/explique melhor essas 3 perguntas, junte o código que já tem e vai ter uma resposta bem esplicada prometo :)

Comment: Na verdade é um table em HTML. O que estou fazendo é uma tela de pedidos. Eu seleciono o produto numa combo, clicar no botão "Inserir no Pedido", e o produto vai aparecer numa tabela logo abaixo. Quando eu salvar o pedido, vou varrer essa tabela, cujos dados estarão num array (ou algo que o valha) e inserir no banco de dados.

Answer (score 1):

Você realmente precisa mandar cada novo produto imediatamente pro servidor? Se sim, você vai precisar usar algum tipo de AJAX para se comunicar com o servidor sem recarregar a página.

Mas se você puder "esperar" para mandar tudo de uma vez, seu problema passa a ser apenas de javascript: basta ler os campos e inserir uma linha em uma tabela ou um elemento em um `div`. Isso é extremamente facilitado por bibliotecas como [jquery](http://jquery.com/), por exemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
<form>
    <h2>Inserir Novo Telefone</h2>
    Nome: <input id="nome" type="text"/><br>
    Telefone: <input id="telefone" type="text"/><br>
    <input type="button" onclick="$('#telefones').append('<div>Nome: '+$('#nome').val()+' - Telefone: '+$('#telefone').val()+' </div>')" value="Adicionar" />
</form>

<div id="telefones">
    <h2>Telefones</h2>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Este código "cadastra" telefones em javascript, colocando dentro do `div` chamado "*telefones*". Para enviar ao servidor ainda precisaríamos pôr estes valores em forms, mas você pode gerar estes campos mudando a string dentro do `.append()` para gerar novos inputs. Eu aconselho a estudar um pouco esta biblioteca, ela inclusive facilita o uso de AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Em uma [resposta a outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6756/227), fiz um exemplo de como popular uma tabela a partir de um array em javascript.

#### [Código funcional no Jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/p57w5/)

Sugiro usar este exemplo como base. Basta atualizar o array e chamar o método de paginação para incluir o produto.

Se não quiser paginação, basta fazer alguns pequenos ajustes no *loop* para remover os limites relacionados à página atual, isto é, incluindo todos os itens.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui fica uma sugestão com jQUery. Não sei se você usa javascript puro, jQuery, Mootools ou outra biblioteca de Javascript...

```
$('#adicionarFruta').on('click', function () {
    var $fruta = $('#frutas option:selected');

    // ignorar se fôr a primeira opção do select
    if ($fruta.val() == '0') return false;

    // verificar se o produto já está na tabela
    if ($('#carrinhoCompras input[name^=' + $fruta.val() + ']').length) return false;

    var novaLinha = '\
    <tr> \
    <td>' + $fruta.text() + '</td> \
    <td><input name="' + $fruta.val() + '" value="1" /></td> \
    <td><button>-</button></td> \
    </tr> ';

    // adicionar nova linha à tabela
    $('#carrinhoCompras ').append($(novaLinha));
});

// codigo para o botão que remove linhas da tabela
$('#carrinhoCompras').on('click', 'button', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/z62VL/)