# Como passar variáveis entre páginas PHP via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Estive a fazer uma pesquisa em PT e EN sobre como passar variáveis de uma página para outra via JavaScript, embora tenha encontrado muita informação continuei com a dúvida de qual a melhor forma para o fazer.

Eu tenho alguns campos duma tabela (paginada) com filtro, via JavaScript que filtra consoante os elementos presentes nessa mesma tabela. Mas quando eu passo de página o filtro que usei é apagado, porque é chamado de novo o meu *script* de filtro.

Eu quero manter o filtro ativo na tabela mesmo mudando de página.

Minha pergunta é diferente de [Paginação simples em jQuery/Javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6740/paginacao-simples-em-jquery-javascript), pois já tenho paginação, já tenho filtros, já tenho tudo a funcionar. Só que sempre que mudo de página o filtro desaparece. 
Como passar as minhas variáveis do filtro para a outra página para serem utilizadas no meu *script* de filtro?

Comment: Podes usar exemplos que fazem isso. Aqui está um exemplo: http://www.jtable.org/demo/pagingandsorting

Comment: possível duplicata de [Paginação simples em jQuery/Javascript](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6740/paginacao-simples-em-jquery-javascript)

Comment: por cookie uai, mais fácil....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Três maneiras de fazer isso:

- Passar o filtro por Ajax para o servidor, e guardar na sessão para utilização posterior
- Guardar o filtro em um cookie gerado e consumido pelo JavaScript
- Guardar o filtro no `localStorage` (menos suportado, não funciona em browsers mais antigos)

Exceto pelo problema de compatibilidade do `localStorage`, as três soluções me parecem igualmente boas. Use a que tiver mais afinidade com o código que você já tem.

Comment: O problema é mesmo esse, a página destina-se a pessoas que podem ter browsers antigo e os cookies desativados. 
Quanto a primeira opção isso não afetaria o desempenho quando estiverem muitos utilizadores com login efetuado?

Comment: Olha, você não tem muitas outras opções se não puder confiar no armazenamento client-side (no próprio browser). É session, banco de dados ou sistema de arquivos. E você precisa passar essa informação para o servidor. Mas não devem ser tantas requisições assim, mesmo com muitos utilizadores, duvido que todos eles estarão ordenando a tabela ao mesmo tempo, a maioria deve ficar no padrão.