# Comunicação entre javascript e PHP

Tags: php, javascript, sql

Olá, sou iniciante em php e javascript e estou com dificuldades para criar tabelas iterativas.
No meu caso, tenho uma tabela inicial: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando selecionar a linha que desejo verificar mais detalhadamente os acidentes (no caso a opção é São Paulo), uma nova tabela é aberta em uma caixa de diálogo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até ai tudo bem, já consegui identificar qual a linha que estou clicando mas não consigo passar essa informação para o código php, pois ele teria que acessar o banco de dados e trazer as informações referente a cidade selecionada.

Alguma dica?

```js
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("tr[rel=modal]").click( function(ev){
    // Efeitos de transição para aparecer a janela semelhante um alerta
      ev.preventDefault();
  
  var cidade = $(this).attr("id"); //Essa variavel carrega a informação da linha selecionada
      }
                             </script>
```

```html
<tr href="#janela1" rel="modal" class="read checked" id="<?=$linha['cidade']?>">
         <a id="<?=$linha['cidade']?>"></a>
         
         
        <td><?=$linha['cidade']?></td>
        <td><?=$linha['acidentes']?></td>
        <td><?=$linha['fatais']?></td>
        <td><?=$linha['ano']?></td>
        <td><?=$linha['meta']?></td>
        <td><?=$linha['farol']?></td>
  
           </tr>
```

Editei a pergunta pois acredito que assim fica mais fácil entender minha dúvida.

tentei aqui de uma forma semelhante, porém é preciso dar f5 para que a opção selecionada seja ativada, caso não de f5, permanece na opção selecionada antes de atualizar a página. $(document).ready(function(){

$("tr[rel=modal]").click( function(ev){   ev.preventDefault();

var indicador = $(this).attr("id"); 
$("#janela12").load('valida2.php', {acc:indicador});
 no valida2.php coloquei 
$_SESSION[indicador]=$_POST['acc'];

Tem mais alguma dica? estou quebrando a cabeça aqui

Consegui resolver colocando a janela modal para abrir uma página externa. Agora estou com problema nessa janela modal, na primeira vez que ela abre as abas de navegação dela não funcionam, já na segunda vez elas funcionam normalmente. Isso se repete, tentativa impar não abre e par abre. Outro detalhe é na mascara, que após 4 clicks ela da uma bugada, ficando sumindo e aparecendo algumas vezes. vou editar o tópica para melhor visualização do código.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   
 $("tr[rel=modal]").click( function(ev){
  
        ev.preventDefault();
  
  var indicador = $(this).attr("id");
  $("#janela12").load('tabelas.php', {acc:indicador});
  
  
        var id = $(this).attr("href");
 
        var alturaTela = $(document).height();
        var larguraTela = $(window).width();
     
        //colocando o fundo preto
        $('#mascara').css({'width':larguraTela,'height':alturaTela});
        $('#mascara').fadeIn(300); 
        $('#mascara').fadeTo(300,0.8);
 
        var left = ($(window).width() /2) - ( $(id).width() / 2 );
        var top = ($(window).height() / 2) - ( $(id).height() / 2 );
     
        $(id).css({'top':top,'left':left});
        $(id).show();  
  
  
  
  
  
  
    });
 
    $('#mascara, .fechar').click(function(e){
  
   if( e.target !== this ) 
          return;
   $('#mascara').fadeOut(30);
   $('.window').fadeOut(30);
   $('#mascara').hide();
   $('.window').hide();
   
  });
 });
```

```html
<div id="mascara"></div>
       <div class="window" id="janela1">
               
        <div id="janela12"></div>
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como passar variáveis entre páginas PHP via JavaScript?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12241/como-passar-vari%c3%a1veis-entre-p%c3%a1ginas-php-via-javascript)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Posso fazer o JavaScript escrever PHP?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90095/posso-fazer-o-javascript-escrever-php)

Answer (score 2):

Não é possível "passar" variáveis do Javascript para o PHP, pois cada um funciona em locais diferentes, o inverso só pode ocorrer quando o documento é renderizado.

O Javascript (puro, como no caso, pois existem variações que rodam backend) roda no cliente, ou seja, no computador de quem está acessando.

Já o PHP é uma linguagem de "back-end" ou seja, executa no Servidor que está rodando a aplicação.

Desta forma, para ter essa interação é necessário utilizar uma requisição HTTP (Post,Get,Push,etc...).

Para que essa requisição ocorra sem que você troque de página, é necessário que seja feita uma chamada assíncrona (pois se fosse uma chamada síncrona, seu front seria direcionado para aquela url).

Para isso você pode utilizar o [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp).

Exemplo:

```
  function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Eu acredito que utilizando o Jquery o Ajax fica mais amigável para quem está começando.

Comment: Ok, ai não precisaria criar uma página para cada cidade né?
Mas como ficaria a parte do `if`, acredito que não precisaria, seria apenas enviar a var cidade = $(this).attr("id") para o innerhtml?

@lucas-queiroz-ribeiro

Comment: Não sei exatamente como você vai exibir a informação, mas basicamente, você enviaria esse ´id´ como um campo POST para o PHP, e o PHP te devolveria as informações que você precisa (como um array ou algo do tipo), então no Javascript você popularia seu HTML com essas informações. (Tem gente que gera o HTML no PHP e devolve para o Javascript, mas é péssimo para manutenção do código, então evite)

Comment: tentei aqui de uma forma semelhante, porém é preciso dar f5 para que a opção selecionada seja ativada, caso não de f5, permanece na opção selecionada antes de atualizar a página.

$(document).ready(function(){
   
 $("tr[rel=modal]").click( function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
  
  var indicador = $(this).attr("id");
  $("#janela12").load('valida2.php', {acc:indicador});

no valida2.php coloquei $_SESSION[indicador]=$_POST['acc'];

Tem mais alguma dica? estou quebrando a cabeça aqui

Comment: tentei aqui de uma forma semelhante, porém é preciso dar f5 para que a opção selecionada seja ativada, caso não de f5, permanece na opção selecionada antes de atualizar a página.     `$(document).ready(function(){   
 $("tr[rel=modal]").click( function(ev){   ev.preventDefault();  
var indicador = $(this).attr("id"); 
$("#janela12").load('valida2.php', {acc:indicador});
 no valida2.php coloquei 
$_SESSION[indicador]=$_POST['acc'];`
 
Tem mais alguma dica? estou quebrando a cabeça aqui

Comment: Você diz marcar o check que você está clicando ? Se for isso, quando você usa o `ev.preventDefault()` você interrompe tudo que iria acontecer normalmente.

Comment: Na minha tabela não coloquei nenhuma check, queria que as informações fossem enviadas apenas com o click sob a linha desejada.
Removi a parte do `ev.preventDefault()` porém continuou da mesma forma.

Quando carrego a página pela primeira vez, se eu selecionar qualquer item, ele não será carregado. Porém ao dar F5, e selecionar um novo item, o item que será mostrado é o que selecionei antes do F5.

Comment: O que você quer dizer com selecionado ? Provavelmente você esteja pegando os registros direto do PHP quando carrega a página, logo, se um arquivo estiver como "selecionado" ele só vai ser alterado quando você recarregar a página, o ideal é que quando você envie essa informação para o Servidor e queria selecionar um item, faça isso manualmente através de Javascript

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que você disse. Os dados cadastrados estão em um banco de dados, formando assim a primeira tabela. Ao clicar sobre a linha que desejo ver mais detalhes, uma janela modal deve ser aberta e os dados serão carregados de uma nova tabela no banco de dados.

Comment: E o que você diz como selecionado ?

Comment: selecionado seria a linha que desejo ver mais detalhes, da primeira tabela.

`<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("tr[rel=modal]").click( function(ev){`

Comment: Então, o que "muda" é o css certo ? pra ficar mais escuro, isso você tem que tratar via Javascript.

Comment: Consegui resolver colocando a janela modal para abrir uma página externa. Agora estou com problema nessa janela modal, na primeira vez que ela abre as abas de navegação dela não funcionam, já na segunda vez elas funcionam normalmente. Isso se repete, tentativa impar não abre e par abre.
Outro detalhe é na mascara, que após 4 clicks ela da uma bugada, ficando sumindo e aparecendo algumas vezes.
vou editar o tópica para melhor visualização do código.

Answer (score 2):

Minha resposta não responde totalmente sua pergunta mas de alguma maneira pode te ajudar. Eu uso em algumas aplicações proprietárias o datatables.net. É um framework próprio para lidar com a captura de dados e com a formatação Das tabelas, é feito em JavaScript e se adapta muito bem com php ( com outros frameworks CSS também se for o caso) 
Vc verá no site que há exemplos mostrando essa "troca" de informações entre o php e o JavaScript. Como outros colocaram, não é possível passar dados direto do php para o JavaScript, mas Eh possível sintetizar isso fazendo uma chamada ao php usando ajax e JavaScript e processando/tratando o retorno.

Comment: eu dei uma olhada no site, porém não consegui achar um exemplo que envia a opção selecionada para o servidor. Mas obrigado pela ajuda.