# Adaptação de script 'mostrar mais' com javascript

Tags: php, javascript, paginação

Estou utilizando um script que foi postado aqui no stackoverflow, que é para limitar a exibição dos posts acompanhado de um link 'mostrar mais', para que carregue outra quantidade de posts.
Segue o [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/6FzSb/2/)
Obs: Se for preciso, eu posto o código completo aqui na pergunta.

Ele começa carregando três posts, e a cada clique carrega
Gostaria que me tirassem dúvidas:
Eu não estou limitando o tanto de registro que irão aparecer no SELECT feio com PHP, então se houverem 200 registros, todos serão exibidos, mas graças ao script de mostrar mais, apenas os três primeiros serão exibidos na pagina. Minha dúvida é: quando o usuario carregar a página, esse load será feito com o total de posts do banco, ou o total do javascript?

Outra dúvida: Se eu começar exibindo apenas 3 posts com javascript, e não limitando o SELECT com php, mesmo que haja 100 registros, influenciará no SEO?

Comment: Acho que a postagem do link falhow, edite a pergunta com o link.

Comment: Obrigado pelo aviso. Atualizei!

Answer (score 2):

Para grandes quantidades de conteúdo isto sera um problema serio, o aconselhável e fazer paginação  dos teus posts, isto e, em vez de carregar os "200 posts" existentes no seu banco de dados e deixar toda essa informação ser controlada pelo javascript para mostrar de 3 em 3, seria mais aconselhável realizar uma query especifica que utilize skips, no caso realizar uma consulta mais otimizada afim de pegar apenas os dados necessários,  um exemplo disto seria:

```
SELECT FIRST 20 SKIP x * FROM TableName
```

Neste caso voce seleciona apenas os 20 primeiros registros e trabalha com eles, a requisição ao servidor e menor de primeira vez e com isto voce garante que apenas o que o usuário quiser acessar sera baixado.

Respondendo as suas duvidas:

### Quando o usuario carregar a página, esse load será feito com o total de posts do banco, ou o total do javascript?

Como voce nao limita a quantidade de posts no seu select ele recebera o total do banco de dados, o javascript apenas ira mostrar ele de pouco em pouco.

### Se eu começar exibindo apenas 3 posts com javascript, e não limitando o SELECT com php, mesmo que haja 100 registros, influenciará no SEO?

Esta e uma otima pergunta :)

Imagine a seguinte situacao, voce entra no [The New York times](http://www.nytimes.com), seu jornal preferido, para ver apenas as noticias mais recentes, por que voce acompanha todos os dias. imagine se eles utilizassem o método do qual voce descreveu, no caso do new york times, eles possuem no mínimo 34mil publicações, o load destas informações de uma so vez ou travaria o seu navegador ou se estivesse usando dados acabaria com seu pacote rsrs.
mas o  foco nao é esse, eu não posso lhe afirmar com certeza mas quanto mais uma pagina e lenta menos usuários são adeptos a utiliza-las.

Referencias recomendadas para implementar uma páginação:

[Paginação assíncrona com jQuery, Ajax e MySQL](http://clubedosgeeks.com.br/programacao/php/paginacao-assincrona-com-jquery-ajax-e-mysql)

[Paginação automática com PHP e jQuery](http://www.devmedia.com.br/paginacao-automatica-com-php-e-jquery/31348)

[Paginação com jQuery e PHP - Youtube](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwignvburP7JAhVGD5AKHa7xCAIQtwIIHTAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DEHiLflz37gY&usg=AFQjCNHlP1GlV2TXdF1WYfBa0IcXJUyc6A)

[Paginação simples em jQuery/Javascript - Stackoverflow BR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6740/pagina%C3%A7%C3%A3o-simples-em-jquery-javascript)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta de muita valia! Entao como ficaria esses skips? Porque eu não estou limitando a query, e atualmente tem 18 registros, mas em uma semana ultrapassará os 50, e um usuário acessando através de dados ira ficar sem, pois carrega vídeos até.. Eu preciso limitar, e so depois fazer a ação com javascript, mas tenho uma duvida: Vamos imaginar que eu te 20 registros e que meu javascript mostra de 2 em 2. Com um skip na query, eu conseguiria fazer com que ele acompanhasse o script de carregar mais?

Comment: Highlander, pode complementar a resposta?

Comment: Posso, irei adicionar algumas referências para te ajudar mas já logo te adianto, pesquise por paginação, no seu caso usando php+ajax

Comment: Entendo perfeitamente. Eu só gostaria de uma resposta mais clara, porque, não sei se estou correto, mas me parece que com "SELECT FIRST 20 SKIP x * FROM TableName", os primeiros 20 serão selecionados, e o meu javascript exibe de 5 em 5. Tá, até ai tudo bem, mas e quando chegar no 20? o servidor buscará mais 20? Porque da forma atual meu select busca TODOS.